# How to serve staticfiles in Django 2.* when DEBUG = False?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I've stucked with deploying Django 2.* on production server.

When i set

```
DEBUG = False
```

Styles in admin page simply stopped serving by debugger or something and i have no clue or ideas how to serve static files.

My settings\actions:

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Then just

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and no styles in admin =(

Will be appreciate for any help.

Comment: You should add the web server you are using. Because it has to serve the static files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this, the most common being to configure your web server (nginx/apache) to serve the static files for you.

However, if you just want to get up and running quickly, you might consider using [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/#quickstart-for-django-apps). It is easy to set up and works well in most situations.

Comment: thank you!

solution:

pip install whitenoise then

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',